# Rails: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, simple-form

I just did a `rails g scaffold Feedback feedback:string user_id:integer`. When I go to 0.0.0.0:3000/feedbacks/new it all works fine. But when I try to put the feedback form inside a modal, I get this error: `undefined method "model_name" for NilClass:Class`. I have googled the problem, but can't find a solution that works.

Does someone knows what might be a solution to this?

**feedbacks/_form.html.erb** (I use simple_form)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :feedback %>
    <%= f.input :user_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**feedbacks/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New feedback</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', feedbacks_path %>
```

**feedbacks/_feedback_modal.html.erb**

```
<div id="activate_feedback_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render "feedbacks/form" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**feedbacks_controller.rb** (the `new` and `create` action)

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @feedback }
    end
  end

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feedback.save
        format.html { redirect_to @feedback, notice: 'Feedback was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @feedback, status: :created, location: @feedback }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @feedback.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**lelist.html.erb (where I render the modal)**

```
<div class="lelist_body">
<div class="container" id="dk">
    <% if current_user %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6 offset3" id="user_post_area_button">
                <a class="big_fat_feedback_button" href="#activate_feedback_modal" data-toggle="modal">feedback</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= render 'pages/singlePost' %>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= will_paginate @posts %>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<%= render "feedbacks/feedback_modal" %>
```

Comment: Where do you render the modal? Probably `@feedback` isn't accessible from the modal-view, so it's `nil`. the `form_helper` tries to generate a url from the class of `nil`, which is `nilClass`, and doesn't have the `model_name` attribute.

Comment: The `lelist` action in your controller (which renders the `lelist-view`, does it have `@feedback = Feedback.new` ?

Comment: YES! Thats is @Tim. I just added '@feedback = Feedback.new' to the action. Thanks! Post this as an answer and I will accept it :) (I am a little new to rails, could you give a short explanation or a link to where I can read about why I had to do this?).

Comment: It's actually pretty simple, I'll add it to my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lelist action in your controller, which renders the lelist-view should have:

```
@feedback = Feedback.new
```

This is why:

Before you can create a form, in this case for a 'Feedback', you have to create a new instance of this model: (`@feedback = Feedback.new`)

The form is generated with all the attributes of this instance.

A url routes to an action on a controller, and renders a view from there. So the action that renders the page with the modal should **always** create this new instance of the model.

I hope this makes it a little bit more clear, it's hard to explain such a simple thing. The most important is:

**Every variable you use in a view must be created in the action that is rendering that view.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to define @feedback in the controller action where you call the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Is it me but have in your `_form.html.erb` the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
```

But yet in your controller `class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController`

So in saying that when you are calling your form and giving it `@feedback` and not `@feedbacks`. Also when rendering a partial is should most probably look like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :feedbacks=> @feedbacks} %>
```

Also have a look at the ruby on rails guide section [3.4.4 - Passing Local Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it does not find the @feedback variable in your partial.
So better to pass the variable.

```
<%= render 'form', :feedback => @feedback%>
```

In your feedbacks/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(feedback) do |f| %>
```